# OneSignal - help me open URL within existing webView ... I'm so confused

Tags: android, webview, onesignal

I had someone create a very basic WebView app for me which has OneSignal notifications.   The app launches with a splash screen and then two buttons on the main page that sends users to different URL's - in my example below, Google and Stack Overflow.

It's working fine but I'm trying to make changes to open a specific URL when a notification is tapped and can't workout how, despite lots of reading here and the OneSignal documentation.   As a last resort, I thought I would post my code to see if anyone can help this newbiew to app coding !

Basically, I need to fix the launchURL code at the very bottom in the ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler class.  I'm sending the URL as additional data via OneSignal and the app reads it correctly in the launchURL variable (when I view the logcat).

```
public class App extends Activity {


    private static final String WEB_URL1 = "https://google.com";
    private static final String WEB_URL2 = "https://stackoverflow.com";

    View ll_Web;
    WebView webView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    RelativeLayout splash, home;
    View ll_pView, pView;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client2;


    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())
                .init();

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ll_Web = findViewById(R.id.ll_Web);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        splash = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.splash);
        home = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.home);

        ll_pView = (View) findViewById(R.id.ll_pView);
        pView = (View) findViewById(R.id.pView);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(pView.getLayoutParams());
                lp.weight = progress;
                pView.setLayoutParams(lp);

                ll_pView.setVisibility(progress == 100 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                ll_pView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            }
        });
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                webView.reload();
            }
        });


        findViewById(R.id.btn1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                webView.clearHistory();
                webView.loadUrl(WEB_URL1);
                home.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ll_Web.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.btn2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                webView.clearHistory();
                webView.loadUrl(WEB_URL2);
                home.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ll_Web.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                home.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                splash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, 3 * 1000);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (ll_Web.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

            if (webView.canGoBack() && !webView.getUrl().equals(WEB_URL1) && !webView.getUrl().equals(WEB_URL2)) {
                webView.goBack();
            } else {
                home.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
                    webView.clearView();
                } else {
                    webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
                }
                ll_Web.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else
            super.onBackPressed();

    }

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        //client2.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();


    }



class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
        // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it.

        @Override
        public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
            OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
            JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
            String launchURL;

            if (data != null) {
                launchURL = data.optString("launchURL");
                if (launchURL != null) {
                    Log.i("OneSignalExample", "launchURL value: " + launchURL);


           //        How do I send the LaunchURL to open webview???
           //        webView.loadUrl(launchURL);


                }


            }

        }
    }


}
```

I didn't write this code but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of others searching for a similar issue, my working code is below.  As a novice, I'm not sure if it's the best solution but it's working for me with the testing I've been doing.

Thanks again to @nimi_moradi for the advice which helped me solve my issue.

```
class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
    // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it and
    // puts the launchURL additional data into a string for use in the main activity
    public static String launchURL;

    @Override
    public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
        OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
        JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
        //public String launchURL;

        if (data != null) {
            launchURL = data.optString("launchURL");
            if (launchURL != null) {
              //  Log.i("OneSignalExample", "launchURL value: " + launchURL);
            }
        }

    }
}



public class App extends Activity {


    private static final String WEB_URL1 = "https://google.com";
    private static final String WEB_URL2 = "https://stackoverflow.com";

    View ll_Web;
    WebView webView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    RelativeLayout splash, home;
    View ll_pView, pView;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client2;


    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())
                .init();

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ll_Web = findViewById(R.id.ll_Web);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        splash = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.splash);
        home = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.home);

        ll_pView = findViewById(R.id.ll_pView);
        pView = findViewById(R.id.pView);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(pView.getLayoutParams());
                lp.weight = progress;
                pView.setLayoutParams(lp);

                ll_pView.setVisibility(progress == 100 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                ll_pView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            }
        });
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                webView.reload();
            }
        });


        //Splash screen and main menu (unless launchURL exists)
        (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if ("".equals(ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler.launchURL) || ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler.launchURL==null){
                    // Show home screen with menu buttons
                    home.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                // Show splash screen for three seconds
                splash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, 3 * 1000);


        // if launchURL contains data, open that
        if (!"".equals(ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler.launchURL)) {
            home.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ll_Web.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            webView.clearHistory();
            webView.loadUrl(ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler.launchURL);

        }

        // Menu button one tapped - Google
        findViewById(R.id.btn1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                webView.clearHistory();
                webView.loadUrl(WEB_URL1);
                home.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ll_Web.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        // Menu button two tapped - Stack Overflow
        findViewById(R.id.btn2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                webView.clearHistory();
                webView.loadUrl(WEB_URL2);
                home.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ll_Web.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (ll_Web.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

            if (webView.canGoBack() && !webView.getUrl().equals(WEB_URL1) && !webView.getUrl().equals(WEB_URL2)) {
                webView.goBack();
            } else {
                home.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
                    webView.clearView();
                } else {
                    webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
                }
                ll_Web.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else
            super.onBackPressed();

    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        //client2.connect();

    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();


    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

do it like you with button

```
    if (launchURL != null) {
                Log.i("OneSignalExample", "launchURL value: " + launchURL);


                webView.clearHistory();
                    webView.loadUrl(launchURL);
                    home.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ll_Web.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 


            }
```

i think webview is not  created when set url for it , add action listener in onStart if you can

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart()
   {
        super.onStart();
     OneSignal.startInit(this)
            .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())
            .init();

       }

     }
```

or at least after `setContentView(R.layout.main);`
like here

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
          OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new 
                   ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())
                      .init();
```

Comment: I did already try that but getting this error  -   

    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.clearHistory()' on a null object reference

Comment: I'm really hoping to get an answer to this ... to me, it sounds like the 'null'  object is the 'webView' part, so I'm guessing I may need to reference it differently if it's in the onCreate method :(

Comment: maybe webView is not created yet in onesignal callback, check that doing what i do in updated answer solve problem or not

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me but those changes didn't help.   

I have done some further testing though and found that it's actually working if the app is already open???   Not sure if that additional information is helpful for this issue.

Comment: if the app is open it means webview is already created, but when click on notification when app closed webView not created yet , try to save data in variable and when webview is created change it's url , use debug to find your solution

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience ... I took your advice and created a static variable in the ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler class and then used that variable in the activity.  Not working 100% right now, but I'm on the right track thanks to @nima_moradi